# SQL If NOT EXISTS Syntax error

Tags: sql, syntax

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT prereqListID
               FROM   dbo.tblPreRequisiteList
               WHERE  NOT prereqListID IN (SELECT FK_prereqID
                                           FROM   dbo.tblPreReqStudentAnswers
                                           WHERE  FK_applicantID = @appID))
```

I have a syntax error in this statement that I can't seem to identify.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is actual error?

Comment: What follows the `IF`?

Comment: Can you please share the entire statement?

Comment: Also please state RDBMS. For some reason I assumed SQL Server. `dbo.tblPreRequisiteList` makes that look a reasonable assumption but please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing the code in the question will give the error

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

You need to follow it with another statement/block

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT prereqListID
               FROM   dbo.tblPreRequisiteList
               WHERE  NOT prereqListID IN (SELECT FK_prereqID
                                           FROM   dbo.tblPreReqStudentAnswers
                                           WHERE  FK_applicantID = @appID))
BEGIN
SomethingHere:
END
```